# Unable to Integrate Facebook in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, empathy, gwibber, facebook, online-accounts

Facebook was working fine as recently as a week ago.

But for whatever reason, the online account for facebook had been deleted from my System Settings. When I try to re-integrate, a browser window pops up and just displays "Success!" and nothing happens.

Does anyone have a solution to this?
Also, if you do, could you explain it very easily - I'm new to Linux.

Edit: Here's a picture of the problem from another user. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH2Le.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. Best to join launchpad (if you haven't already) and add your tick to this issue...

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/signon-ui/+bug/1120737

At this point there appears to be no work around for this. I've temporarily overcome this by downloading Pidgin from the software centre and use that.

Hope that helps...

Comment: I also got fed up trying to find a way out, completely removed all those packages (empathy, telepathy, online accounts, etc.) and installed **Pidgin** although I wasn't happy with its level of integration with Unity. However, I've managed to improve this as can be seen in my answer to the question **"How to install Adium theme for Pidgin?"** in addition to a couple of tweaks like **using ubuntu-monochrome icons to make a matching icon style for Pidgin**, etc.