# Unable to add Facebook account

Tags: facebook

Recently my Facebook account stopped working with Ubuntu. It was showing up as being unverified, and when I tried pressing the "Grant Access" button, it just opened up a page on Firefox that just contained the plaintext, "Success". The URL was something about a successful Facebook login.

I tried removing the account and re-adding it, but the same thing happened and it failed to add.

Any idea what's going on and how to resolve this?

Comment: "Something about a successful Facebook login" is pretty vague. Can you be (a whole lot) more specific about what you're trying to do? What are you trying to add your FB account *to*? Are you accessing it through a browser? Which browser?

Comment: Duplicate of:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/260956/unable-to-integrate-facebook-in-ubuntu-12-10